# what's the proper way to check if terminating AWS EC2 instance is successful using boto3?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, boto3

I use the following code to terminate an aws EC2 instance. What is the proper way to check whether the termination is successful?

```
s = boto3.Session(profile_name='dev')
ec2 = s.resource('ec2', region_name='us-east-1')
ins = ec2.Instance(instance_id)
res = ins.terminate()
```

Should I check whether

`res['TerminatingInstances'][0]['CurrentState']['Name']=='shutting-down'`

Or ignore `res` and describe the instance again to check?

Comment: The documentation is not ideal here, but I suspect that if you are terminating a single instance then the absence of an exception should suffice.

Comment: I use a web server to call this termination code. Do you happen to know what exception `terminate()` could throw?

Comment: In response to the question of what exceptions/errors might be thrown by terminate (or the waiter in the other thread), unfortunately I don't think there is a good answer. This is, in my opinion, one of the major weaknesses of Python in general and boto3 specifically -- good documentation on error handling is lacking and the nature of Python itself makes it impossible to determine.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The best way is to use [the `EC2.Waiter.InstanceTerminated` waiter](http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/ec2.html#EC2.Waiter.InstanceTerminated).

It polls `EC2.Client.describe_instances()` every 15 seconds until a successful state is reached. An error is returned after 40 failed checks.

```
import boto3

client = boto3.client('ec2')
waiter = client.get_waiter('instance_terminated')

client.terminate_instances(InstanceIds=['i-0974da9ff5318c395'])
waiter.wait(InstanceIds=['i-0974da9ff5318c395'])
```

The program exited once the instance was in the terminating state.

Comment: Would you mind showing a working example and demonstrate which error to catch? Many thanks~

Comment: Code added. The last line simply waited (hung) until the instance was terminated.

Comment: Thanks John. I have one more question: in my server I defined my own `BadRequestError` and processed them uniformly so the users don't see 500 error. Do you happen to know what error `waiter` would throw?

Comment: Is that a response from your web server? If so, it does not apply to a `waiter`, since the waiter is merely calling AWS APIs to determine instance status, which is unrelated to your web server.

Comment: In my web app, the user clicks a button to terminate the instance. Under the hood, the web app calls boto3, which may ends up with error. Maybe I just catch everything for the `waiter.wait`